# Hex object in CF

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am trying to convert some java code (below) to Coldfusion but am running into an error

> Variable HEX is undefined

How can I create a Hex object in CF?

```
<cfset input='{"id":7,"attempts":1,"notifications":[{"action":"UPDATE","message":{"id":0,"sender":"","body":"{\u0022TableId\u0022:930002,\u0022TableName\u0022:\u0022DEMOGRAPHIC\u0022,\u0022TableAction\u0022:\u0022UPDATE\u0022}"}}]}'>

<cfset key = "xxxx">

<cfscript>

secret = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec' ).Init(key.GetBytes("UTF-8"), 'HmacSHA256');
mac = createObject('java', "javax.crypto.Mac");
mac = mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(secret);
digest = Hex.encodeHexString(mac.doFinal(input.GetBytes("UTF-8")));
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Where in this code did you intend to create the variable "hex"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Coldfusion 10 or higher, then you can use the internal [Hmac](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html) function instead of all Java create objects. [DEMO](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=b0e31551-ab5b-4654-95ba-d3248baffaef/1c1d4542-cc64-4f41-8b8c-5c6c6048fb6e/67adb197-c86d-4143-a337-9ea39f05aedc.cfm)

```
lcase(HMac(input, key , 'HMACSHA256'))
```

---

If not, then I think you can define Hex variable like this.

```
Hex = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex")
```

But you should not need it. You can use BinaryEncode function in Coldfusion.

```
digest = lcase(BinaryEncode(mac.doFinal(input.GetBytes("UTF-8"))))
```